# Listing files older than 60 days inside a docker container

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run a role, using ansible shell module, to delete files (with a specific path — `/myhome/dir/` and naming — `*.ext`) inside a docker container (`mycontainer`), older than 60 days.

I have done it using shell like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Delete files /myhome/dir/*.ext older than 60 days inside 
  shell: docker exec -t mycontainer find /myhome/dir1/ -name "*.ext" -type f -mtime +60 -delete
```

This is working, but I'd like to do the same approach but using an Ansible built-in module.

Comment: You might have to separate it into a `find` and `file` task.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to use the module `community.docker.docker_api` or one of its siblings.

Comment: Or use the [`connection: docker`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/community/docker/docker_connection.html) on that task and then `find:` would work as expected if the container has a copy of python, otherwise `raw:` allows injecting arbitrary shell commands

Comment: @MadPhysicist your answer just needed a few more info to be absolutely correct. Can you have a look at my edit and undelete it ? It should be accepted IMO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the below to work, you will need to target your docker container from your inventory using the [`ansible_connection: docker` plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_connection.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-connection).

Dummy inventory example:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    dummy_docker_container_name:
      ansible_connection: docker
```

The ansible [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) module should help you get a list of the files you want to delete:

```yaml
- name: Find old files
  find:
    age: 60d
    age_stamp: mtime
    hidden: yes
    recurse: yes
    patterns: "*.ext"
    paths: /myhome/dir1/
    register: list_of_old_files
```

You can then pass the list of files over to the [`file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html) module to delete them one-by-one:

```yaml
- name: Delete old files
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ list_of_old_files.files }}"
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I make this work inside docker "mycontainer"?

Comment: @Fr0zt. Oh right.

Comment: Will try that and report the results. Thanks